# java 8 not seeing desired output with using map with filter

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I see different result with using map with filter than using foreach with filter:

```
public class test1
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", "a");
        map.put("c", "a");

        Set<String> vs = new HashSet<>();
        vs.add("b");
        vs.add("c");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        vs.stream()
                .filter(a -> map.containsKey(a))
                .map(c -> list.add(c));

        System.out.println("here "+ list.size());

        vs.stream()
                .filter(a -> map.containsKey(a))
                .forEach(c -> list.add(c));

        System.out.println("here "+ list.size());
    }
}
```

here is the output:
here 0
here 1

can somebody explain?

Comment: `.map()` is not terminal operation, btw

Comment: is there any point you don't understand, ashutosh?

Answer (score 1):

*Terminal operations* produces a *non-stream*, result such as primitive value, *a collection* or no value at all. Terminal operations are typically preceded by intermediate operations which return another `Stream` which allows operations to be connected in a form of a query. e.g. `forEach()`

*Intermediate operations* return another `Stream` which allows you to call multiple operations in a form of a query. **Intermediate operations do not get executed until a *terminal operation* is invoked** as there is a possibility they could be processed together when a terminal operation is executed. e.g. `map()`

In the following code, you didn't invoke a *terminal operation* in the last such as `forEach()` or `collect()`. That's why `c -> list.add(c)` isn't executed along with `.filter(a -> map.containsKey(a))`.

```
vs.stream()
  .filter(a -> map.containsKey(a))
  .map(c -> list.add(c));
```

Examine the result after using the following code snippet instead of above one,

```
vs.stream()
   .filter(a -> map.containsKey(a))    // intermediate
   .map(t -> list.add(t))              // intermediate
   .collect(Collectors.toList());      // terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

In our first stream you need terminal operation.

Without this, `map` is not executed.

Second stream have terminal operation (`foreach`) and whole stream is executed.

Add terminal operation to first stream(like `count()`) and you will see

`Here 1
Here 2`